# .NET web service maximum array length quota

Tags: c#, web-services, web-config, windows

I wrote a chat windows application when I'm trying to receive(Download) a record.wav (28K) from my service from the client.There is an error:

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter [http://tempuri.org/:DownloadFileResponse](http://tempuri.org/%3aDownloadFileResponse). The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type BerryWindowsApplication.BerryWebService.DownloadFileResponseBody. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML.

I searched and found out that I should create new binding in Edit WCF configuration.I changed MaxBufferSize,MaxReceivemessageSize,MaxBufferPoolSize,MaxArrayLenght,MaxBytesperRead to 2147483647 and maxdepth to 32 and transfermode to buffered and messageencoding to Mtom,But there is same Error.
Following codes are used in this program:

in webservice side:

```
[WebMethod()]
public byte[] DownloadFile(string FName)
{
   Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Files\"+FName);
   return bytes;
}
```

in webconfig:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="binding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.106/Service.asmx"
   binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding"
   contract="BerryWebService.WebService" name="binding" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

in windows application side:

```
if (fdDownload.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string s = sr[2].ToString().Split('\\').Last();
                    var byteArray = bs.DownloadFile(s);
                   byte[] b1= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(byteArray.ToString());
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fdDownload.FileName, b1);
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fdDownload.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                    fs.Write(b1, 0, b1.Length);
                    fs.Flush();
                    fs.Close();
                    cn.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("File downloaded Successfully", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Comment: You mixing asmx(`WebMethod`) and wcf(your config file). You should stay with one technology

Comment: Change the `bindingConfiguration` attribute from `bindingConfiguration=BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService"` to `bindingConfiguration="binding"` in your endpoint, or change the `name` attribute on your `<binding>` element to "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentLibraryService".  Otherwise you will continue to get the default values for that binding.

Comment: I dont understand your meaning? My web method is used for giving file name and return bytes of file but in config I configured the max size of bytes

Comment: Dear Tim ,I corrected the name but there is same error

Comment: I wrote in contract name of my project plus interface of it.is it right?what sould i write i contract?

Comment: I understand my problem.I configured my app.config in client side. I just configured web service config and it did not work